# jquery (ajax) and php search not showing swedish letters result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
if($(this).val().length > 0) { 
    var p = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'search_ajax_4.php',
        cache: false,
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            name: encodeURIComponent($('input#input_field').val())
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#append_data').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

This is search_ajax_4.php code:

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) 
{
    $search_string = $_GET['name'];
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM cashbackengine_retailers WHERE title LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" AND (end_date="0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR end_date > NOW()) AND status="active" LIMIT 5';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo $results['title']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure character encoding is correct in your PHP file as well as your database collation.

I'm guessing your PHP page charset isn't declared or your database collation isn't one that supports the characters being entered.

Comment: I have put this charset code in my php file now. But it is still not showing results on swedish letters.
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: what about your database collation? @Jack Reacher

Comment: My database collation was utf8_general_ci .
Now I change it to utf8_swedish_ci.

Comment: You will need to re-insert the data after changing the collation